# Finding the smallest possible sample size of a 2x7 contingency table, given row-wise proportions and relation between row marginal counts

Tags: sample-size, contingency-tables

NB: this is not about power analysis.

Consider the following table, which has the following row-wise proportions:

|  | cat_1 | cat_2 | cat_3 | cat_4 | cat_5 | cat_6 | cat_7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.3222449 | 0.302041 | 0.208163 | 0.089796 | 0.044898 | 0.028571 | 0.004082 |
| B | 0.111468 | 0.115756 | 0.118435 | 0.143623 | 0.182208 | 0.155413 | 0.173098 |

We know that:

- the proportions are likely rounded
- the marginal total count $n_{2+}$ (i.e. the total count of observations for row B) is somewhere between 2.5 and 3 times the marginal total count $n_{1+}$ of row A, such as $2.5n_{1+} < n_{2+} < 3n_{1+}$
- the observations are independent and are human beings ([the data comes from another question on a study about human weight](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/632570/which-hypothesis-test-should-i-use/)), so the true total sample size $n_{++}$ is unlikely to exceed a few billions.

We want to know what is the smallest possible sample size $n_{++}$ that satisfies the conditions above.

Here is how I would approach the issue:

1. For row A, using [continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) to find all possible marginal total counts $n_{1+}$ that can satisfy the rounded proportions $p_{11}, ..., p_{17}$ for this row (and that do not exceed billions).
2. Same thing for row B: retrieving possible $n_{2+}$ satisfying the rounded proportions $p_{21}, ..., p_{27}$
3. Iterating over all possible combinations of counts found in steps 1 and 2, keeping only combinations satisfying $2.5n_{1+} < n_{2+} < 3n_{1+}$
4. Then simply looking at which of these remaining combinations gives the smallest sample size.

I was wondering if there is some mistake that I don't see with this approach, if there's some room for improvement, or if there is a better way to solve the problem. Of course, I'm interested in a description of a solution, but my question is for self-learning, so any information is useful.

If this kind of problem has a specific name (i.e. finding minimal possible counts for a series of related proportions), I'm also interested in references about it.

Comment: I suspect this question might be off-topic. If it's the case, tell me where to migrate it (stackoverflow, math.stackexchange.com ?), and I'll copy it myself there (unless someone else beats me to it). As a side note, this is not a homework question, so I did not tag it as "self study", but as it's just for self-learning purposes I don't see a problem with someone else adding the tag.

Comment: I recall solving this problem in several instances here on CV.  In each case I remarked that the brute force method works well: sequentially increase $n$ until the first time it's either too large or when all the proportions $np_i$ are satisfactorily close to integral.  Plotting the maximum absolute roundoff error as a function of $n$ is revealing.  Another technique, which I recently found success with, applies when some of the proportions are expected to correspond to tiny counts (1, 2, or 3 perhaps), because their reciprocals and small multiples thereof give you a good initial guess of $n.$

Comment: BTW, note that "a few billions" is overkill in this example, because $n=10^6$ clearly gives exact results.  As a rule of thumb, when data are reported with $d$ decimal digits, you can usually find a good solution $n\le 10^{d-1}.$ // Finally, *Mathematica* implements something like this with its [Rationalize](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) function. As an example, `x = {322449, 302041, 208163, 89796, 44898, 28571, 4082} / 1000000.; LCM @@ (Denominator /@ Rationalize[x, 0.00001])` returns `245`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go the way of rational approximations, there are functions in R package `MASS` that you can use:

```r
MASS::fractions(B)
[1] 27867/250000 11976/103459 22458/189623 27728/193061   2847/15625   5669/36477   7581/43796
```

(I only use your `B` here as `A` seems more difficult ...). But I will go the way of @whubers comment:

```r
closest_int <- function(x) round(x)

finding_n <- function(from, to, test, epsilon=1E-4) {  
  stopifnot(from<to, round(from)-from==0, round(to)-to==0, 
            from>=1)
  maxerr <- numeric(to-from+1)
  names(maxerr) <- as.character(from:to)
  cand_n <- numeric() 
  
  for (n in from:to) {
    eps <- max(abs(closest_int(n*test) - n*test))
    maxerr[n-from+1] <- eps
    if (eps <= epsilon) cand_n <- append(cand_n, n)
  }
  return(cand_n)  
}

finding_n(1, 10000,B, 0.001)
[1] 1866
```

but with a stricter tolerance (last argument above `0.001`) it struggles to find solutions, they become unrealistically high.

Note that

```r
sum(B)
[1] 1.000001
```

indicating that rounding error in fifth place